# How to clone elasticsearch index mappings

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How to clone elasticsearch (v5.3) index mappings to another index using php/python. Problem is that I don't have the mappings of these indexes. We are trying to increase shard count before moving to a cluster, current setup is a single node and all index are having 1 shard.

Flow I have in mind - 
create new index -> clone mappings -> re-index -> point the alias to new index.

Will help If someone can point in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think path my be changed to:

1. clone mapping eg. from HTTP GET elastik:9200/my_index
2. create new index with version suffix from setting cloned in point 1 / or modified in point 1
3. reindex with data
4. modify aliases eg. my_index point ot new index with version suffix

In symfony I use Elastic Client and recreating index is simple

```
$builder = ClientBuilder::create();
$builder
            ->setHosts([
                [
                    'host' => $host,
                    'port' => $port,
                ]
            ])
            ->setConnectionParams($this->clientOptions);

    $this->client = $builder->build();
    $this->client->indices()->delete([
            'index' => $this->index
        ]);

    $this->buildMapping();
```

Is also simple to move code above to symfony cli.